# Python REGEX - Matching String Containing Varying Number of Bookend Whitespaces With "-" in the Middle

Tags: python, regex

Trying to use regex to clean data in a csv file.  Some cells contain `'   -   '` (3 whitespaces on either side) or `'    -    '` (4 whitespaces on either side).  For the case of 3 whitespaces, this works

```py
import re
my_string = '   -   '
test1 = re.search('\s\s\s-\s\s\s', my_string)
test1
```

I want to use wildcards for the `\s` to account for any number of whitespaces the vendor may insert into the data.

I've tried each of the following (including some that aren't listed and none of them work.

```py
test2 = re.search('\s+-\s+', my_string)

test2 = re.search('\s*-\s*', my_string)

test2 = re.search('^\s+-\s+$', my_string)

test2 = re.search(r'\s+-\s+', my_string)
```

According to [Regex101.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5axK.png), one of these should work.
I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.

EDIT:
I don't have enough XP to embed pics, but in my environment "test1" generates "<re.Match object; span=(0,7), match='   -   '>" on the screen.  "test2" generates nothing.

Comment: Can't reproduce. All of your `test2` expressions work and evaluate to `<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='   -   '>`

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm with a jupyter notebook and I never get a "test2" variable or output to the console.  Sounds like something in my setup...

Comment: Also, as an educational side note, if you want to explicitly express either 3 or 4 spaces, your can use `\s{3,4}`. And if you want to assert that there are the same number of spaces on either side, there's `^(\s+)-\1$`

Comment: @JustinNeal Are you inspecting the value of `test2` after the assignment? Assignment statements aren't expressions - they don't evaluate to a value, so there's nothing for jupyter to display

Comment: @Brian61354270, I switched to a different notebook and it's working now.  must have been a glitch in the matrix.